# Changing the initial value of a var in another module

Tags: swift, module, overriding, var, initializer

I am using this module to display an image:
https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView/blob/master/Sources/ImageScrollView.swift

I have added it to my project using CocoaPods and I want to change the value of the var "maxScaleFromMinScale". I just cant figure out how.

First I tried to just override the var which is not possible.

I then tried to override the intializers by just copying and overriding the same ones that are overrided by the creator of the module.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

That does not work, it gives me an error on the top initializer saying that I am not overriding the designated initializer. It feels like I cannot override it since it is not public like the second one. Correct?

Last thing I tried was to make an extension:

```
extension ImageScrollView {
    public func setMaxScale(scale: CGFloat) {
        maxScaleFromMinScale = scale
    }
}
```

That does not work either, maxScaleFromMinScale is an unresolved identifier. This also seems to be because it is an internal var and I do not have access to it (another module). Does this mean that my ONLY option is to copy the whole file and modify the source. Was hoping for a minimal and elegant solution.

If this is the case, why can you override the built in UIKit elements but not this one that I downloaded using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot override the variable/function because it's `internal`. That's the point of access modifiers.

Certain `UIKit` functions are `public` so you can override them.

Comment: So basically, when using modules if something needs changing in their code you have to do the "stupid" thing and just copy the whole thing?

Comment: @Alex Yes. If it's not `public` then it's not meant to be overridden.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the pod file and unlock the file (It prompts to do that on editing), and change

```
var maxScaleFromMinScale: CGFloat = 3.0
```

to

```
public var maxScaleFromMinScale: CGFloat = 3.0
```

Comment: You can also use "static".

Comment: What do you mean "unlock". How can I do this?

Comment: Like I said it prompts on editing, if it doesn't you can just make the variable public.

Comment: @Alex he means directly editing the source code of the pod locally. But in practice you shouldn't do that. Instead, clone the pod if you're applying modifications.